# Is time complexity for this function is O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was reviewing some old notes on algorithms today, and this got me thinking.

> Complexity `O(1)` means execution time for function is independent on data.

So let's suppose we have a function to add all elements in array.

```
int add(int[] array){
    int sum =0;
    for (int i=0;i<ARRAY_MAX_SIZE;i++){
      sum= sum + (i<array.length?array[i]:0);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

where `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE` is maximum possible size of array. I know this code is not efficient i don't want to discuss this. But operator `+` is called same amount time each time and it is not affected by size of data.

Does that means complexity of this function is O(1)?

Comment: The complexity is `O(ARRAY_MAX_SIZE)`. If `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE` is a constant, then `O(ARRAY_MAX_SIZE) == O(1)`

Comment: @Eric that what i thought, but some part of me couldn't accept this.

Comment: Actually, that's not always true. See my answer

Comment: This is why you shouldn't apply big O to code (algorithms are fine, just not their implementations), you can always argue that either the thing doesn't terminate or it terminates in at most some "constant but perhaps ludicrous" number of steps. As soon as you decide on a pointer size, you're in a finite state machine, not a Turing machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. O(1) means constant time, not fast/efficient/optimal.

Big-O complexity ignores the complexity of constant steps. A division (slow) is just as "complex" as an increment (fast).

Comment: You are right, I don't know why, but I assume O(1) means more efficient than O(N), which obviously it was wrong assumption an lead me to ask this stupid question. Thanks for quick answer

Comment: I think *O(0.001)* is where it's already considered not only constant, but fast too :-)

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer is "it depends".

There are two different sets of things happening here:

- `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE` times, you:

  - Increment and test a for loop
  - add to the total
- `array.length` times, you:;

  - access `array[i]`
- `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE - array.length` times, you:;

  - load the constant zero

So the total runtime is

```
t = k_1 * ARRAY_MAX_SIZE +
    k_2 * n +
    k_3 * (ARRAY_MAX_SIZE - n)
```

So you look at how `k_2` and `k_3` compare. Are they basically equal? Then it's `O(1)`. Is `k_2 >> k_3`? Then it's `O(n)`.

Why might `k_2 >> k_3`? Because `array[i]` is accessing memory, and [memory is comparatively very slow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only interesting part is `array[i]` is used only `n` times. This means you add an operation to deference the array to get the `i`th element only `n` times. I wouldn't count this normally, but wouldn't this maybe make it `O(n)`? Just playing devil's advocate.

I would suppose this would be the true `O(1)` equivalent.

```
int add(int[] array){
    int sum =0;
    int len = array.length;
    for (int i=0;i<ARRAY_MAX_SIZE;i++){
        sum= sum + array[i%len] & (i < len ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why is this `O(1)` and not `O(-n)`? Each miss gives me twice as many array lookups!

Comment: @Eric Because the number of references and computations is not dependent on the array length at all.

Comment: I see `array[` once on one side of the `:` and twice on the other. Which side is executed depends on the array length

Comment: @Eric Yes, so there are exactly `(1 + 2) * SOME_CONSTANT * ARRAY_MAX_SIZE = O(1)`  computations/iterations per usage of code.

Comment: No there aren't, because the `? :` operator is short-circuiting, with only one of the two results being evaluated. So one side is evaluated more than the other, and the amount that happens is determined by `n`.

Comment: @Eric you're right, fixed it hopefully. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Make it obvious by doing `array[i%len] & (i < len ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0)`

Answer (score -1):

If you had a maximum array size, then the complexity would be `O(1)`. But this has other consequences. `array.length` would need to be less than `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE,` so `array.length` is bounded by a constant, making the following `O(1)` as well:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + array[i];
}
```

So we'd usually just ignore any limits on array sizes to get useful results for algorithm complexities.

This is obviously assuming that `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE` is maximum possible size of array (as it was defined in the question), and not some other value.

Comment: `array.length` is not required to be less then `ARRAY_MAX_SIZE` for this to "work'

Comment: @Amit How not? The length has to be less than the maximum length, otherwise it's not the maximum.

Comment: You're confusing value with title. Is there anything preventing `array.length > ARRAY_MAX_SIZE`?

Comment: I guess you're free to give variables the wrong values if you want but analysis based on that would be nonsense.